# ReactJS MVC Asp.net: Can not retrieve data from database to view using React JSX

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I hope you guys well in this season

I'm currently doing task build an MVC application with Visual Studio and connect it to an SQL database and using: React JS components should be written using ES6 classes and jsx
Create controlled components. Use state.
Use AJAX inside React components to post to/get from the controller

I have a issue with retrieve data from database to view table. Could you please have a look my code

When i run it, it load the data but doesn't show in the table like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzyaX.jpg)

I checked inspect element/ console and it say

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `Customer`.
>
> ```
> in TableRow (created by Customer)
> in Customer
> in div
> ```

CustomerIndex.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Button, Modal, Header, Image, Container, Divider, Grid, Menu, Segment, Icon, Popup, Form, Table, Label } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import $ from 'jquery';


{/* Model class customer */ }
class Customer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            customerList: []
        };

        this.loadData = this.loadData.bind(this);
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
        this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Customer/GetCustomersDetails",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () { // loading...
                $("#loading").show();
            }
        }).done((data) => {
            $("#loading").hide();
            this.setState({
                customerList: data
            })
        });
        //fetch("/Customer/GetCustomersDetails")
        //    .then(response => response.json())
        //    .then(data => {
        //        this.setState({ customerList: data });
        //    });
      
    }

  
    add(event) {
        // ajax call logic     
        const formData = new FormData(event.target)
        let dataJSON = {}

        event.preventDefault()

        for (let entry of formData.entries()) {
            dataJSON[entry[0]] = entry[1]
        }

        console.log(dataJSON)

        fetch("/Customer/PostAddOneCustomer", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(dataJSON)
        }).then(response => {
            response.json().then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.reload();
            })
        })
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    update(id) {
        //ajax call logic
        var data = {
            name: this.state.name,
            address: this.state.address,
            id: id
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Customer/PostUpdateOneCustomer",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).done((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({
                serviceList: data
            })

        });

    }

    delete(id) {
        //ajax call logic
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Customer/DeleteOneCustomer?customerId=" + id,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (response) {
                NotificationManager.success('Success message', 'Title here');
                window.location.reload(); // refresh the page
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        let customerList = this.state.customerList;
        let tableData;
        console.log(customerList);
       
        
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>

                    <Modal id="modal" trigger={<Button color="green">Add a new customer</Button>}  >
                        <Modal.Header >Add a new customer</Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Content>
                            <Form onSubmit={this.add} ref="form" method="POST">
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Name</label><br />
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a name" name="name" required
                                        minlength="3" maxlength="20" /><br />
                                </Form.Field>
                                <Form.Field>
                                    <label>Address</label><br />
                                    <input placeholder="Type an address" name="address" required /><br />
                                </Form.Field>
                                <Button type='submit'><Icon name="save" />save</Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Modal.Content>
                    </Modal>

                    <Table celled>
                        <Table.Header>
                            <Table.Row>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Customer name</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Action (Edit)</Table.HeaderCell>
                                <Table.HeaderCell>Action (Delete)</Table.HeaderCell>
                            </Table.Row>
                        </Table.Header>
                        <Table.Body>
                            { customerList.map(service =>
                <Table.Row key={service.Id}>
                                <Table.Cell >{service.Name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell >{service.Address}</Table.Cell>
                                    <Table.Cell >
                                        <Modal id="modal" trigger={<Button color="yellow" ><Icon name="edit" />Edit</Button>}  >
                                            <Modal.Header >Details customer</Modal.Header>
                                            <Modal.Content>
                                                <Form ref="form" method="POST" onSubmit={this.update.bind(this, service.Id)}>
                                                    <Form.Field>
                                                        <label>Name</label><br />
                                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Type a name" name="name" placeholder={service.Name}
                                                            onChange={this.handleChange} required minlength="3" maxlength="20" /><br />
                                                    </Form.Field>
                                                    <Form.Field>
                                                        <label>Address</label><br />
                                                        <input placeholder="Type an address" name="address" placeholder={service.Address} onChange={this.handleChange} required /><br />
                                                    </Form.Field>
                                                    <Button type='submit'><Icon name="save" />save</Button>
                                                </Form>
                                            </Modal.Content>
                                        </Modal>
                                    </Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color="red" onClick={this.delete.bind(this, service.Id)}><Icon name="trash" />Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>
                            </Table.Row>
            )}
                        </Table.Body>
                        <Table.Footer>
                        </Table.Footer>
                    </Table>
                </div>
                <div id="loading"><p>Loading...</p></div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}





{/* rendering the component */ }
const app = document.getElementById('customers');
ReactDOM.render(<div><h1 className="anim">Customer Details</h1><Customer /></div>, app);
```

CustomerController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CRUDOnboardingReactJS.Models;

namespace CRUDOnboardingReactJS.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
       private CRUDOnboardingEntities1 db = new CRUDOnboardingEntities1();
        // GET: Customer
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // JSON
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetCustomersDetails()
        {
            var customers = db.Customers.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Name,c.Address }).ToList();
            //return Json(db.Customers.ToList());
            //  if (db.Customers != null)
            // {
             List<Object> array = new List<Object>() { customers};
            return Json(array, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          //  return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                //}
                //return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
         }


        public JsonResult PostAddOneCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) // checking the fields are completed
            {
                var query = db.Customers.Add(new Customer() { Name = customer.Name, Address = customer.Address });
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }

        public JsonResult PostUpdateOneCustomer(Customer customer)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var query = db.Customers.Where(user => user.Id == customer.Id).Select(col => new { col.Name, col.Address }).Single();
                    query = new { customer.Name, customer.Address };
                    db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified; // allow to update the entity
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
            return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }


        public JsonResult DeleteOneCustomer(int customerId)
        {
            var delete = from customer in db.Customers
                         join prodsold in db.ProductSolds on customer.Id equals prodsold.CustomerId
                         where customer.Id == customerId && prodsold.CustomerId == customerId
                         select prodsold;

            foreach (var record in delete)
            {
                db.ProductSolds.Remove(record);
            }

            var c = db.Customers.Where(user => user.Id == customerId).Single(); // delete the customer

            db.Customers.Remove(c);

            db.SaveChanges();

            return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear which the problem is with your code. Could you please be more concise and clear?

Comment: I just fixed it